# Channel Form, make Captcha field required

Tags: safecracker, captcha

I'm using EE 2.9 and have the form below, can you make the Captcha field required?

```
{exp:channel:form channel="test" return="test/thank-you" logged_out_member_id="1" dynamic_title="[question]" status="pending" rules:captcha="required" rules:my_email="required" rules:first_name="required" rules:last_name="required"}
    {label:first_name}
    {field:first_name}

    {label:last_name}
    {field:last_name}

    {label:my_email}
    {field:my_email}

    {label:question}
    {field:question}

    {label:my_nearest_branch}
    {field:my_nearest_branch}

    <label for="captcha">Please enter the word you see in the image below:</label>
    {captcha}
    <input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha" value="{captcha_word}" maxlength="20">

    <input type="submit" value="Ask Question" class="button">
{/exp:channel:form}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, There are two ways to do so.

**Server side:**

In your `{exp:channel:form}` tag, Add parameter `rules:captcha="required"`

**Client side:**

Use jquery.validate.js to make field required.

1. Include this js library: `http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js`
2. Put the class `required` in input field.
3. Use jquery to run the code before form submits:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $(document).on('submit', 'form#myForm', function(event) {
               if($(this).valid()){
                   return true;
               }else{
                   return false;
               }
           });
       });
   </script>
   ```

[Here](http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/) is some classes you can use to validate the form input fields.

Comment: Hi Mufaddal, thanks for help.  I have rules:captcha="required" on the form, but it dons't seem to work for the captcha field.  I'll try the jquery option instead.

Comment: Strange why captcha required rule not working, JQuery is good and I think now is only solution to make this field required. :(